# How to send JSON data instead of logging it to the console

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on a food ordering app in flutter and the API in Express.js with MySql for the database.
I was able to connect to the database and receive the JSON data and console.log() them, but I don't know how to send them to the app.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here's the code.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mysql = require('mysql');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'ala_ainy_db',
    connectionLimit: 10,
});

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {

    pool.getConnection(function (err, conn) {
        if (err) return;
        conn.query('SELECT * FROM restaurants', function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                conn.release();
                console.log('failed');
            }
            rows.forEach((row) => {
                console.log(`ID: ${row.id}, Name: ${row.name}`);
            });
            conn.release();
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: what about `res.send()`?

Comment: You don't send to your app, your app makes a GET request to the server.

Comment: i tried that and it's giving me this error Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: @Crowcoder i know that and i'm doing it but what i mean is that when i add this code res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Handling GET requests to /products'
    }); the client only gets this JSON object {message: 'Handling GET requests to /products'}, and i want it to get the rows as well because like i said i was able to log them to the console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could send your data in response with express `res.json()` or `res.send()` methods.

> **res.json()** Sends a JSON response. This method sends a response (with the correct content-type) that is the parameter converted to a JSON string using **JSON.stringify()**.
>
> **res.send()** Sends the HTTP response. The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an Array.

Example:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mysql = require('mysql');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'ala_ainy_db',
    connectionLimit: 10,
});

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {

    pool.getConnection(function (err, conn) {
        if (err) return;
        conn.query('SELECT * FROM restaurants', function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                conn.release();
                console.log('failed');
            }
            conn.release();
            res.status(200).json(rows);
            
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: i did try that and it gave me this error Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: Could you check your code and see if there is any response send to the client before this.

Comment: thank you, I was sending a response before that, my problem was solved

Comment: i'm trying to accept the answer but it's telling me that i need to wait 3 minutes before accepting it